# PHP compare duplicates from array with multiple string data

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

I have an array with four columns (divided by ";") per index number. The data is coming from a csv file.

Example Data:

```
John = Firstname
Doe = Lastname
Playground = Description 
john.doe@example.com = Email

print_r($dataArray);

Array
(
 [0] => John;Doe;Playground;john.doe@example.com
 [1] => John;Doe;Playground test;john.doe@example.com
 [2] => John;Doe;test Playground;john.doe@example.com
 [3] => Johnny;Dawson;Test Area;john.doe@example.com
)
```

Now I want to remove the duplicates with `array_unique`.

But I only want to compare the "firstname" and the "lastname".

If the firstname and the lastname has multiple results then remove the duplicate entry.

In this case [1] and [2]

```
$finalArray = array_unique($dataArray);
```

array unique will only work if all rows have the same data e.g.

```
 [0] => John;Doe;Playground;john.doe@example.com
 [1] => John;Doe;Playground;john.doe@example.com
```

Goal: Final result

```
Array
(
 [0] => John;Doe;Playground;john.doe@example.com
 [1] => Johnny;Dawson;Test Area;john.doe@example.com
)
```

What is a good way to handle this case?

Comment: If you have two rows with different data but the same first name, which row do you want to keep? The first or second?

Comment: this is not important. the first would be okay because the description may vary (which is okay).

Comment: If it's truly not important, would it be acceptable to filter out only the first and last names and use array_unique on them?

Comment: if i do that how can i get the rest of the data? description and email?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm confused about. If description and email are important, how does it not matter which of the duplicate records you keep?

Comment: i only want to compare the first and the lastname if the rest of data is invalid or wrong then nothing "bad" will happen. first and lastname are the best unique indicators for that comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a` will be unique. notice the array keys that remained the same.

```
foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{
   list($name,$family) = explode(';', $v);
   if( isset($temp[$name.$family]) )
        unset($a[$k]);
   else
        $temp[$name.$fam] = true;
}
```